# How to lower the "heat" level in Just Cause 2?

Tags: just-cause-2

In Just Cause 2, the more you destroy things, the higher the military alert is. It's fine at the beginning, but passed level 3, it's starting to be really crazy, really fast (a dozen of soldiers shooting me after one minute, and 2-3 helicopters on the way).

Since my goal is mostly to have fun destroying things more than shooting, I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve that.

So my question is: how to keep the level of "heat" low while destroying things, and what is the best way to lower it when it's becoming too high to handle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use a mod (for example [Less Psychic Police](http://justcause2mods.com/index.php/mods/other/Gameplay/Less-psychic-police/) or [Less Vehicle Heat](http://www.justcause2mods.com/index.php/mods/other/Gameplay/Less-Vehicle-Heat/)) to increase the threshold of police reaction
2. Run/fly away. Police are only aware of you within a certain range, <strike>so if you call in either an extraction</strike> (can't with heat, forgot about that), or a black market chopper and fly up really high, the heat will fade. Then just bail out/reingress and continue the fun.

Comment: I don't think you can call the black market chopper with heat, though.

Comment: You can call the black market for items/vehicles, just not for extraction.

Comment: @Albort - indeed, it works for that case, I checked. I thought it wouldn't be possible to call him at all during heat (which would actually make more sense, but that's my opinion).

Comment: @Gnoupi - agreed

Answer (score 4):

You basically need to kill all the military and then get the hell out of there, or just get the hell out of there. If you have a fast vehicle (fully upgraded chopper or jet is best), then you can take to the sky with relative ease.

Barring that, you can get some decent speed with the grapple/parachute combination through the forests and up the mountains. And hijack a chopper if need be.

Comment: I'm not sure indeed about the "killing all the military". I observed some strange cases yesterday where nobody is around, but I still hear some radio message calling for reinforcements. I experimented going away at heat 1-2 with the parachute, it goes quite ok for now.

Answer (score 3):

If you are near an ocean or a body of water, go into the water. The military is stupid so they wont notice you. not too shallow though because then you will stand up.

Answer (score 2):

If you play on easy, your heat will not rise as quickly, and will return to normal faster. When your heat gets high, move to a different area controlled by a different faction. I found this makes it very easy to keep heat below level 3.

Comment: I'm already playing in casual, so that's why I was surprised by the amount of soldiers shooting me down that fast. About changing territory, why will it help? I mean, If playing in a faction territory already, they send some troops from time to time, but that's all. Why changing to another faction will help more?

Comment: When I was playing I found that the military never followed me across faction lines. If I had a high heat level, and moved to a different area, it would drop quickly. I'm not sure if this is supposed to be part of the game, but it always worked for me.