# How do you get rid of the army?

Tags: just-cause-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to lower the “heat” level in Just Cause 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4116/how-to-lower-the-heat-level-in-just-cause-2)

Are there more ways to get rid of your Heat level other than running away and/or killing off all enemies in the area? Like in GTA, where you have garages to paint your car or can change clothes?

Comment: There aren't any garages or clothes changes, sadly :(  Get good at parachute/grappling into the deep forest - if you move fast enough, they have trouble chasing.

Comment: Except for the helicopters, but that just means a free helicopter for you :D